# Why am I keep getting error:- page does not exist

Tags: php, codeigniter

Good day!

am new to code igniter, I have been practicing with tutorial on the manual to create a blog,

but my view page keeps saying page not found,

this is my index:

```html
<h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>

<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>


    <h3><?php echo $news_item['title']; ?></h3>
    <div class="main">
            <?php echo $news_item['text']; ?>
    </div>
    <p><a href="<?php echo site_url('news/'.$news_item['slug']); ?>">View article</a></p> <?php endforeach; ?>
```

this is the view page for each post : view.php

```html
   <?php
echo '<h2>'.$news_item['title'].'</h2>';
echo $news_item['text'];
```

this is my routes:

```html
 $route['news/create'] = 'news/create';
`$route['news/create'] = 'news/create';
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';`
```

and i confirmed that i have the details in the database.

thank you if you can help

Comment: If you get 404 Page not found, then your routing must be wrong. Make sure it points to an actual controller and method, and you have a view file set properly etc. What URL are you trying to access?

Comment: thank you, i am trying to access this link using 
 the post title slug from the database 
  http://localhost/tut/index.php/news/testing-this-news

Comment: Hmm, you dont have an apache VirtualHost set? I would have thought http://localhost to be the root of the project, it could be that's your issue. You can create a fake domain name as a virtualhost which apache will respond to, then you edit your OS'es hosts file to point 127.0.0.1 to your fake domain. I like to call mine dev.whatever.com, but it canm be anything! Once you have a proper domain set, this problem might go away. Firstly though, do other links work?

Comment: do you mind working me through how to setup virtual host?

Comment: i have set up the virtual host but still get error 404 page not found

Comment: So you can access `http://whateverHostNameYouPicked` and you get the home page?

Comment: my url is like this: http://tut.local/index.php/news/testing-this-news

Comment: use .htaccess to redirect everything through your front controller so you don't need index.php to appear in the URL

Answer (score 0):

index.php is missing in your site_url you have to,
1] add index.php in config.php or
2] use index.php in anchor tag [like: /index.php">View article]